# Lazily load files at random from large directory

Tags: python, random, lazy-loading

I have about a million files in my directory, and their number is likely to grow.
For machine learning, I would like to randomly sample from those files without replacement. How can I do this very quickly? os.listdir(path) is too slow for me.

Comment: Either use some other storage mechanism such as a database, or else divide the files into subdirectories.

Comment: This really is an OS question, not a language question.  I don't believe Linux/MacOS gives you any way to read the contents of a directory other than sequentially.

Comment: @JohnGordon
A database sounds like a workable solution to me. Can you point me in the right direction in terms of libraries/packages that I could use to build an efficient database that makes my task possible?

Comment: Any python database library should work.  Just pick one that meets your needs.  Sqlite3 is built in to python, and it seems to have good documentation, so I would start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have about a million files in my directory ... os.listdir(path) is too slow for me.

This is the core of your problem, and it's solved by a technique I've generally heard referred to as *bucketing* your files, though a web search for this doesn't seem particularly helpful.

Bucketing is generally used by programs that need to store a large number of files that don't have any particular structure - for example, all the media files (such as images) in a MediaWiki instance (the software that runs Wikipedia). Here's the Stack Overflow logo on Wikipedia:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg

See that `0/02` in the URL? That's the bucket. All files in Wikipedia will be *hashed* by some algorithm - for example sha256, though it won't necessarily be this - and `02` will be the first two hex digits of that hash. (The `0` before the slash is just the first digit of `02`; in this case it's used as a second level of bucketing.)

If MediaWiki just stored every single file in one massive directory, it'd be very slow to access the files in that directory, because although OS folders can hold arbitrarily many files, they just aren't designed to hold more than a few thousand or so. By *hashing* the contents of the file, you get what looks like a random string of hex digits unique to that file, and if you then put all the files that start with the same first two hex digits (like `02` in a folder called `02`, you get 256 folders (one for each possible value of the first two hex digits), and critically, **each of those 256 folders contains a roughly equal number of files**.

When you're trying to look up particular files, like MediaWiki is, you obviously need to know the hash to get to the file, if you store it in this way. But in your case, you just want to load *random* files. So this will work just as well:

- Hash all your files and bucket them (possibly with additional levels, e.g. you might want files like `12/34/filename.ext`, so that you have 65,536 buckets). You can use things like [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.file_digest) or command-line tools like `sha256sum` to obtain file hashes. You don't need to rename the files, as long as you group them into directories based on the first few hex digits of their hashes.
- Now, each time you want a random file, choose a random bucket (and possibly random sub-buckets, if you're using additional levels), then choose a random file within that bucket.

Doing that will be a lot faster than using `listdir` on a directory with a million files and then choosing randomly among those.

---

<sub>Note: I'm just using MediaWiki as an example here because I'm familiar with a few of its internals; lots of software products do similar things.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide some alternative approach. Basically, what you want is not scanning and statting directory files in one huge sweep, but just read directory entries and sample subset of them. On linux/UNIX this amounts to readdir() syscall, which is small and return direntry after direntry till it is exhausted (NULL returned). Then you could use [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to do actual sampling.

In Python os.scandir I believe calls something like readdir.

So, some (untested) pseudocode

```
import os
import math

folder = 'AAA'

sampled = []
nof_samples = 10

with os.scandir(folder) as it:
    for i, entry in enumerate(it):
        if i < nof_samples:
            sampled.append(entry.name)
            continue

        n = math.random.randrange(i)
        if n < nof_samples:
            sampled[n] = entry.name
```